# C++ fmt library not working

Tags: gcc, c++, libraries, visual-studio-code

Hi guys I'm a C++ beginner and I just found that the fmt lib is really interesting. But I ran into a problem when trying to use it. I used homebrew to install fmt lib `brew install fmt` .I check the fmt installation using `apt-file search /usr/include/fmt/format.` and it then returned `libfmt-dev: /usr/include/fmt/format.h` .I tried to build a sample project to test it as follows:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print("The answer is {}.\n", 42);
}
```

After I tried to complie it with gcc11 it returned

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmrL6RH.o: in function `void fmt::v8::print<int>(fmt::v8::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v8::type_identity<int>::type>, int&&)':
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include/fmt/core.h:3209: undefined reference to `fmt::v8::vprint(fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v8::basic_format_args<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Honestly I don't understand what this problem is... The syntax looks good and there is nothing wrong with the compiler and IDE. Could you help me out? Thanks in advance.

Update:
@steeldriver told me that it was because the fmt lib was not linked. So I added some commands in the `tasks.json` file:

```
...
 "tasks": [
        ...
        "args": [
            ...
            "-lfmt", "-L~/usr/include/fmt"
        ]
]
...
```

`/usr/include/fmt` is the path to fmt lib. @steeldriver recommended this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486880/how-to-link-fftw3-libraries-for-c-in-vs-code-in-ubuntu.

Comment: What OS and version are you using?

Comment: @cocomac it's ubuntu linux 20.04.3, operating on virtual machine on macbook pro

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libfmt-dev` instead of homebrew.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you my friend. I just tried this code and then I tried include the full path to the fmt lib `#include </usr/include/fmt/format.h>`, but it returned ``/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBkstet.o: in function `void fmt::v6::print<char [19], int, 0>(char const (&) [19], int&&)':
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:1514: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::vprint(fmt::v6::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v6::format_args)'``. It seems that it has something to do with homebrew?

Comment: after  `sudo apt install ilbfmt-dev` i uninstalled fmt lib using `brew uninstall fmt`. Notice that v8 changed to v6. @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: Does it still show the same error (related to `linuxbrew`) even after removing the version from homebrew? Can you try rebooting? Maybe it is still trying to using the homebrew version from cache.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it look like the issue now is that it's still using the homebrew version of `ld` (perhaps because the OP placed `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/` early in their `PATH`)

Comment: Yes. I just rebooted the system and still the same error. Can I change the path? @steeldriver

Comment: @WilliamB it would likely be something added to one of your shell startup scripts when you installed linuxbrew - look in ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile etc.

Comment: I found the /.profile by this code `xdg-open .profile`. And I found these text in this file `
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` I guess these lines is what you meant. Is that right? Should I change it? BTW, I have uninstalled homebrew @steeldriver

Comment: Yes if you no longer intend to use brew, you can remove (or comment out - using `#`) the line `eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

Comment: Yes I just did that. But the result is confusing. I changed the gcc compiler path configuration in visual studio code. The result is as follows ``/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdxHuLT.o: in function `void fmt::v6::print<char [19], int, 0>(char const (&) [19], int&&)':
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:1514: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::vprint(fmt::v6::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v6::format_args)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`` @steeldriver

Comment: It's hard to comment on that without seeing the actual gcc command(s) generated by VSCode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134281/discussion-between-williamb-and-steeldriver).